# How to find the most popular used devices for an app on Google Play?

Tags: android, testing, google-play

In our team we would like to buy the most used devices for our app published on Google Play for testing.

Any idea how to get this information?

Answer (score 2):

you can go to statistics and then select active devices in quickreport. this will get you some statistics of the top devices for your app.
[image]